# How To use MYSQL Select Query to find an Apostrophe followed by an Uppercase letter, made from a typo (typographic) error

Tags: mysql, select, data-cleaning, uppercase, apostrophe

I needed an MySQL Query to find all rows which contained a text pattern like

> It'S hot

(an apostrophe followed by an uppercase letter), made by mistake (a typo), when the typist held the shift key too long while typing fast.

Answer (score 3):

```sql
SELECT artist, title
  FROM songs 
  WHERE BINARY title REGEXP '^.*\'[A-Z]+'
```

`BINARY` forces case sensitivity,

`^` starts at beginning of data field,

`.*` matches any character(s)

`\\'` escapes a single quote

`[A-Z]` matches uppercase A thru Z

`\+` matches anything after it, even nothing i.e. end of line

Comment: `^.*` is unnecessary.